# Match string begining with word ending with comma

Tags: regex

working in Graylog with regex expressions.  Given this string:

FPWR2120_Access, AccessControlRuleName: Guest IPS and Malware Inspect, Prefilter Policy:

I am trying to extract "Guest IPS and Malware Inspect"

Using this expression:

```
^.*AccessControlRuleName:(.+)$
```

I get all the characters after AccessControlRuleName.  How do I tell it to stop extracing once it reaches the first comma?  Do I need to use a boundry or an anchor?

Comment: Try `^.*AccessControlRuleName:([^,]+)` https://regex101.com/r/3FqQRb/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^,]` instead matching any char except a comma.

Then match the trailing comma to make sure it is present.

```
^.*\bAccessControlRuleName:([^,]+),
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5WbqmX/1)

Comment: ++ though just `\bAccessControlRuleName:([^,]+),` would be good enough.

Comment: @anubhava You are right, that would be enough :) I took the same start of the pattern as the OP .

Answer (score 1):

You can use look ahead positive and look behind positive for this purpose:

```
(?<=AccessControlRuleName:)[\w ]*(?=,)
```

Link: https://regex101.com/r/FF8zCb/1

There is an explanation of this concept in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/2183174